# geth eth_sendRawTransaction return "invalid sender"

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, raw-transaction

I am not very good at English ! Please forgive me .

I use the sendRawTransaction to send a signed transaction .
[image]

The geth returns an error and I can not find the reason

[image]

Comment: Seems that transaction's signature is invalid. Please update the question with the code you used to sign your transaction.